# If Jones buys a used radio, what is the probability that it will be working after an additional 8 years?

Tags: probability, random-variables

The number of years a radio functions is exponentially
distributed with parameter  = 1=8. If Jones buys a used radio, what is the
probability that it will be working after an additional 8 years?

is this simply the probability density function

$$  f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac18e^{-\frac18x},  & \text{when $x\ge$ 0} \\
0, & \text{when $x\lt$ 0}
\end{cases}  $$

and then all I have to do is find $P(x \gt 8)$?
Would the interval of the integral be from 8 to infinity? I don't think this is correct?

Comment: Yes, you integrate from $8$ to $\infty$.  Alternately, you may already know that $\Pr(X\le x)=1-e^{-x/8}$.

Comment: I calculated the intergral from 8 to infinity of xf(x) using integration by parts, after evaluating for infinity and 8 I got 8e^(-1+(x/8)), is this correct?

Comment: No integration by parts, you can either write it down immediately or use substitution. The answer will be $e^{-1}$.  You had the wrong integral, one that comes from expectation. We want $\int_8^\infty (1/8)e^{-x/8}\,dx$.

Comment: thank you, I forgot that you only add the x in the integration when calculating expectation.